# Enum values with different types in JSON

Tags: arrays, json, enums

Is it possible to pass enum values with different types as keyvalue pairs in JSON schema?

For example:

```
    "availableproducts" : {
    "enum" : ["Produce 1" : 20.00 , "Product 3" : 30.00 , "Product 7" : 10.00 , "Product 17" : 00.00 ]
   },
```

Or do I need to list the arrays separately and bring them together as keyvalue pairs?

Thanks

EDITED:

Is this how the schema definition should be like? ( Note that I am linking to the products from a separate schema.)

```
"availableproducts" : {
        "description" : "available products for this option ",
        "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
                   "type" : "object",
                    "properties" :{
                           "availableproducts" : {
                               "$ref": "http://mystore.com/schemas#product/properties/name" ,
                               "type" : "string",
                           },

                           "productcost" :{
                                "type" : "number",
                           },
                   }
                },


    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JOSON is wrong, ENUM should be a array,

So try;

```
  "availableproducts" : {
                     "enum" : [{"Produce 1" : 20.00 , "Product 3" : 30.00 , "Product 7" : 10.00 , "Product 17" : 0.00 }]
 }
```

Hope this is what you wanted..!!!

Comment: Hey thanks, how would you pre-define this in the schema file? Would it be an object?

Comment: if it is array then it will be like this when you convert in json object

Comment: See my edited answer above. I have tried to create a schema object that would generate the following code. Not all products would be available in this option, hence the enum solution. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Just to make sure it is clear. `ENUM` above is the `enumerated type` and not a variable container.